# Is my hardware capable of running ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10

need help about installing ubuntu 12.10 on my computer. these are my computer hardware details.

- Intel Pentium III Processor 797 MHz
- 384 MB of RAM
- 10 GB Hard drive space.

on C-drive am having Windows XP Pro (its working ok with this hardware). want to install ubuntu 12.10 on D-drive which is 10 GB. will it run smoothly if i install?

many thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: why not just try it out?

Answer (score 1):

No , ubuntu 12.10 can not run at this configuration , you can use ubuntu 10.10 is light and easy for use. Also graphics same as XP so you can take experience of LINUX.

The minimum memory requirement for Ubuntu 12.10 is 768 MB of memory and 5 GB of disk space for Ubuntu Desktop

Comment: ubuntu 10.10. is it similar to 12.10? read on website that 12.10 got new features and easy to use. i am poor in using command line type of user interface. will prefer to use interface like windows. can 10.10 be used like that?

Comment: i downloaded windows installer for ubuntu 12.10. its given on website that its easy to install with this installer. is there something like this for 10.10?

Answer (score 0):

Your hardware isn't capable. Ubuntu 12.10 require at least 768 MB of RAM. You try to install Lubuntu or Xubuntu on this hardware. Maybe also you should use "Alternate" install CD, wich require less RAM.

Comment: will lubuntu or xununtu similar to ubuntu in features and usage?

Comment: Of course Unity interface has more features than lightweight interfaces LXDE and FXCE, but basics will be the similar and you can run all software, which you can run on Ubuntu.